# Patter matching variable and string

Tags: bash

## bash script

Hi! I would like to make a bash script that contolli if the content of a var variable does pattern matching with the string ending with ABC?

Comment: what have you tried doing

Comment: I tried to do this:
   var="hellowordABC"
   grep $var "*.ABC"

Comment: Check the `grep` man page: the syntax is `grep pattern [file ...]`. If you omit the files, grep will scan stdin, which is what Moti's answer is using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the bash builtins:

```
# with glob patterns
if [[ $var == *ABC ]]; then echo "$var ends with ABC"; fi

# with regular expression
if [[ $var =~ ABC$ ]]; then echo "$var ends with ABC"; fi
```

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there

```
 var="hellowordABC" 
 echo $var | grep ".*ABC$"
```

Or using builtin conditions

```
[[ $var =~ ABC$ ]] && echo "var ends with ABC"
```